# Create a table in Pages

Tags: pagination, applescript

I am looking to automate the generation of a number of tables containing data within a new iWorks Pages document.

Online there is a wealth of information related to doing this in Numbers, but absolutely nothing to help with doing this within a Pages document and the method seems to differ slightly.

The kind of table I am trying to produce is a simple table with heading columns and then data below e.g.

```
Column1     Column2     Column3     Column4
 data         data       hello       data
 moredata    moredata    data        hello
 data         data       data        data
```

It is possible in Microsoft Word by doing:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"

    set myDoc to make new document

    set myTable to make new table at myDoc with properties ¬

        {allow auto fit:true, allow page breaks:true, column options:¬

            {default width:1.0, preferred width:25, preferred width type:¬

               preferred width percent}, number of columns:¬

            4, number of rows:12, spacing:2.0}

end tell
```

But how can it be done in pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example, this works on the last version of **Pages**

```
tell application "Pages"
    set myDoc to make new document
    tell page 1 of myDoc to set myTable to make new table with properties {column count:4, row count:12}
    tell cell range of myTable
        set width of columns to 120
        set text wrap to true
        set alignment to center

        -- to set value of the headers and some cells
        set j to 1
        repeat with i in {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "data cell 1", "data cell 2", "hello", "data cell 4", "moredata", "moredata", "data", "hello"}
            set value of cell j to i
            set j to j + 1
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: For me this stopped working with Pages 8.1. I always get `Error: Invalid column count`. Anybody else have this?